# How to link Django project to APNS .p8 key on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: django, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

I'm currently trying to add push notifications to my iOS app. My backend server is a Django server deployed on Google Cloud Platform.

I've been using [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) on my backend and I was having trouble actually sending messages. When I try to send a message to a device, I get this error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/AuthKey_0123456789.p8'`

(Note I replaced the name of the file with dummy data).

I placed my `.p8` file in the root of my directory and then ran `google app deploy`. Does anyone know where I should actually be storing the file and also what the path for the `APNS_AUTH_KEY_PATH` settings key should be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/issues/455#issuecomment-603894527).

Basically, you can keep the `.p8` file in the root of your app's directory, and then have your push notifications settings look like this:

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
        "APNS_AUTH_KEY_PATH": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "your_cert.p8"),
        "APNS_AUTH_KEY_ID": "YOUR_AUTH_KEY",
        "APNS_TEAM_ID": "YOUR_TEAM_ID",
        "APNS_TOPIC": "YOUR_TOPIC", # usually same as device bundle name
        "APNS_USE_SANDBOX": True, #or false
}
```